# Scrollview not working inside view pager fragment

Tags: android, scrollview

I am using a Scroll View in a fragment which is used inside a view pager. But the scroll does not seem to work.

```
 <ScrollView
      android:id="@+id/scrollview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
...
...
...
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the layout of the fragment. But scrolling does not seem to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
scrollview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the"wrap_parent" in the "scrollview" and its child views:

android:layout_height="wrap_parent"

Answer (score 0):

Make scroll view top (i.e parent) with fill parent height and width.

Answer (score 0):

use NestedScrollView like below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".FragmentContactInfo">
    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```